# moving webkit gradient backgrounds?

Tags: html, css, webkit, tumblr, gradient

I'm a beginning programmer and honestly, I'm trying to change a background on my tumblr theme. I want a gradient that moves (for reference: the exact one on [this page.](http://jubileethemes.tumblr.com/)
trust me when I say I've asked the owner; they weren't very responsive and deferred me to look it up, which I, knowing nothing at all about code, could not do.)

So. Okay. Yes. I want to change my background to THIS. I clicked around a bit and I found that when you right click and inspect the page elements, drop down to the html body, she has a webkit gradient with changing values for her colors. I attempted to copy and past it into my own theme, but I only captured the moment at which I had copied the gradient, not the entire changing values thing.

What am I doing wrong? How do I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/uanuw4Lp/)**

Trying to make the gradient CSS to work with more browsers, original code only works with webkit and moz.

The site uses the following code:

js

```
var colors = new Array(
  [255,255,255],
  [181,96,137],
  [136,210,221],
  [255,107,109],
  [173,88,143],
  [100,161,161]);

var step = 0;
//color table indices for: 
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.003;

function updateGradient()
{
var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

var istep = 1 - step;
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "#"+((r1 << 16) | (g1 << 8) | b1).toString(16);

var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "#"+((r2 << 16) | (g2 << 8) | b2).toString(16);

$('#gradient').css({
    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)",
}).css({
    background: "-webkit-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)",
}).css({
    background: "linear-gradient(to right, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)",
}).css({
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='"+color1+"', endColorstr='"+color2+"',GradientType=1 )",
});

  step += gradientSpeed;
  if ( step >= 1 )
  {
    step %= 1;
    colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
    colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];

    //pick two new target color indices
    //do not pick the same as the current one
    colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;

  }
}

setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

respective css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#gradient {
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, from(rgb(213, 239, 243)), to(rgb(213, 239, 243)));
}
```

html for demo

```
<div id="gradient"></div>
```

---

## for applying the same to body

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


body {
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, from(rgb(213, 239, 243)), to(rgb(213, 239, 243)));
}
```

js

```
var colors = new Array(
  [255,255,255],
  [181,96,137],
  [136,210,221],
  [255,107,109],
  [173,88,143],
  [100,161,161]);

var step = 0;
//color table indices for: 
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.003;

function updateGradient()
{
var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

var istep = 1 - step;
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "#"+((r1 << 16) | (g1 << 8) | b1).toString(16);

var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "#"+((r2 << 16) | (g2 << 8) | b2).toString(16);

 $('body').css({
   background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});

  step += gradientSpeed;
  if ( step >= 1 )
  {
    step %= 1;
    colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
    colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];

    //pick two new target color indices
    //do not pick the same as the current one
    colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
    colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;

  }
}

setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

Comment: So, okay. Thank you for that. But now what do I do? I need to put that into my HTML for my Tumblr theme. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you go to edit the tumblr theme (I personally copy it into a file locally to keep as a back up and edit). Add the div id="gradient" somewhere in the main block. The css will be towards the top of the tumblr theme inside a stye tag. Then add the javascript towards the bottom of the file and wrap it inside these tags <script type="text/javascript"></script> That should all work.

Comment: Thank you! I already added the div id="gradient". where should i put the CSS, in the body or the head? and by style tag, you just mean <style> </style>, correct? 

EDIT: 

I just put all that in, and instead of being my background, my entire blog has just turned into a big gradient -_- HELP. here's a link for reference as to what's happening (side blog: i have a blog to run, so i'm setting up a demo on my side blog): http://negatives-and-glossies.tumblr.com/

can someone help me get it as just a background, and not my entire blog? Thank you!

Comment: @soren : sorry for the late reply! I have made an edit, now the gradient will apply to the body and you can have your blog go live..:)

Comment: @4dgaurav I forked that jsfiddle as it's so beautiful.

Comment: AH THERE WE GO THANK YOU SO MUCH <3